# jQuery fancybox-overlay being inject multiple times

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've recently set up a website [here](http://www.serverchoice.com/), I'm having an issue with Fancybox for jQuery.

I noticed the symptom by scrolling down and click the 'Take DC Tour' link, this loads a fancybox(ajax) and plays a video. Lovely! However once I close the lightbox and click the link again, it creates a second fancybox-overlay element.

As far as I can see I have everything correctly set up.

If anyone has encountered this or has any ideas please chime in.

Comment: I would advise you not to compress your files until you are sure everything works fine (difficult to debug like that) also, I wouldn't edit the original fancybox js and css files but set another custom initialization js file. Last but not least, paste your code in your question and don't ask people to click in your links and analyze your code, SO is not a public debugging service

Comment: Very fair points, i'll get an uncompressed version uploaded. Thanks for taking the time to look into it a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, it happened because I had multiple instances of fancybox and on opening, the "create" method was called multiple times.

The solution for me was to set live=false

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({live: false});
```